# Disable Google Earth Plugin auto-tilt

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-earth-plugin

This post from 2012: [Is there any workaround for disabling the "auto tilt when zooming" feature of the Google Earth plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054480/is-there-any-workaround-for-disabling-the-auto-tilt-when-zooming-feature-of-th) talks about the auto-tilt feature of Google Earth and the plugin.

In both cases it seems to be referring to the behaviour that tilts the display towards the horizontal as one zooms in.

I have the reverse problem in Maps and am wondering if there is a solution. If you start the Earth plugin in Maps (Click Earth in top right corner), then tilt the display to 45 degrees, then zoom in, the view automatically tilts back to the vertical overhead view as you zoom in.

If there is no option in native Maps, is there an option to stop the auto tilt when starting the plugin from code please? (in V2 or V3 maps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is that there is no solution at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Disable tilt is now available.

You can turn off this automatic tilt (Tools > Options > Navigation > Navigation controls; Mac: Google Earth > Preferences > Navigation > Navigation controls).

https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148186?hl=en-GB

Comment: Thank you, this was/is an annoying feature which should have been off by default!

Answer (score 1):

Simply press 'R' to exit the ground view, it works